# New to cider making. Apples treated with lemon juice

Tags: cider

I processed 100lbs apples for pie filling, apple butter, whole chunks with cinnamon, etc.

I have a lot more in the freezer, but they were doused with lemon juice to keep them from browning until the cooking starts.

Are these lemon juice doused apples good for cider making? Or should I just pick more?

Comment: What was your process for dousing? How much lemon juice per lb of apples are you talking about?

Comment: make a gallon and find out ;)

Answer (score 1):

They will be fine for cider making, the yeast will just enjoy the extra nutrients.